# js popup window to play .flv flash video using jwplayer.swf

Tags: javascript, flash

I have to have many small thumbnails on a page and each one needs to open up to a full size (640x480) video with controls when clicked.

Comment: Can you post an example link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised no Javascript experts took this. My solution is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>PopUp Player using JWPlayer</title>
    <meta   http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
      input
      {
        width:                                    300px;
        height:                                    32px;
        font:              bold 13px Verdana, serif;
        text-align:                              center;
        color:                                  #fe0320;
        background:            url(player.gif) repeat-x; // 1px wide, 32px high
        cursor:                                 pointer;
        border:                                       0;
      }

      img
      {
        position:                              relative;
        display:                           inline-block;
        float:                                     left;
        border-width:                                 0;
        margin:                                       0;
        padding:                                      0;
        font-size:                                    0;
        cursor:                                 pointer;
        z-index:                                      1;
      }

      div.clickmecontainer
      {
        cursor:                                 pointer;
      }

      div.clickme
      {
        position:                              absolute;
        display:                           inline-block;
        width:                                     79px;
        top:                                        50%;
        margin-top:                               -15px;
        text-align:                              center;
        color:                                    white;
        font-family:                            Journal;
        font-size:                                1.5em;
        z-index:                                      2;
      }

      div.playerpopup
      {
        position:                              absolute;
        top:                                      100px;
        left:                                     100px;
        z-index:                                    100;
      }
    </style>



    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">google.load('swfobject', '2.2');</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var swf = false;

      function addSwf(file, width, height, id)
      {
        clearSwf();

        if((id != '') && (id != undefined))
        { // alert('The '+gid(id).nodeName+' element with id="' + id + '"\nTop: '+gid(id).style.top + '\nLeft: ' +gid(id).style.left );
          gid('playerpopup').style.top  = ((gid(id).style.top.replace( 'px', '') * 1) - 500) + 'px';
          gid('playerpopup').style.left = ((gid(id).style.left.replace('px', '') * 1) + 60) + 'px';
          setTimeout("swf = true;", 1000); // alert('New nTop: '+gid('playerpopup').style.top + '\nLeft: ' +gid('playerpopup').style.left );
        }
        else
        {
          gid('playerpopup').style.top  = 'px';
          gid('playerpopup').style.left = 'px';
          setTimeout("swf = true;", 1000);
        }

        gid('playerpopup').innerHTML='<a id="player"class="player"href="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">Adobe Flash Player</a><div><input type="button" style="width:'+width+'px;" value="--  C L O S E  --" onclick="clearSwf(); return false;"></div>';

        var flashvars =
        {
          'file':                                   file,
          'frontcolor':                            'd3d3d3',
          'backcolor':                             '000000',
          'lightcolor':                            '6d6c6b',
          'screencolor':                           '373737',
          'id':                                    'playerID',
          'autostart':                             'true'
        };

        var params =
        {
          'allowfullscreen':                       'true',
          'allowscriptaccess':                     'always',
          'wmode':                                 'opaque',
          'bgcolor':                               '#FFFFFF'
        };

        var attributes =
        {
          'id':                                    'playerID',
          'name':                                  'playerID'
        };

        swfobject.embedSWF('player.swf', 'player', width, height, '9.0.124', false, flashvars, params, attributes);
      };


      function clearSwf()
      {
       if(swf)
       {
         swfobject.removeSWF('playerID');
         gid('playerpopup').innerHTML = '';
         swf = false;
       }
      };


      function gid(name)
      {
        return document.getElementById(name);
      };
    </script>

</head>




<body bgcolor="white";>


   <div id="12345" style=" position:absolute; top:606px; left:120px; width:180px; height:30px; z-index:19;">

     <img alt="Preview" src="Preview.jpg" width="80" height="60" onClick="addSwf('video.flv', 640, 503, this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));" />

   </div>

   <div id="playerpopup" class="playerpopup"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using fancybox:

http://fancybox.net/

They have an example with a "swf", I'm sure you can adapt this for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks I looked at this and lightbox and a couple of others that cost around $50. None of them did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html) before and was very pleased with it (video examples are lower on the homepage). You can embed YouTube videos, your own .flv files (using JW Player), Vimeo videos, etc.

Also, it doesn't use any JavaScript framework so it's guaranteed to work with your code.

Comment: I could not determine if it was possible to avoid the obscuring of the page beneath. no response from support...

Comment: you can either activate ShadowBox via JS and set the showOverlay option to false, or edit the actual shadowbox.js and change showOverlay: true to showOverlay: false